Tikzcd diagram broken, with babel
With the following code, I want to output a tikzcd diagram, but perhaps due to babel, the diagram appears broken when displayed. Where should I make modifications to output the diagram correctly? The diagram itself displays correctly in other code, so I believe there may be an issue with the preamble.

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
%%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}  

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % babelとtikzの互換性を確保


\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,cd}  % 追加: 矢印のライブラリ




\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand*{\isoarrow}[1]{\arrow[#1,"\rotatebox{90}{\(\simeq\)}"
  ]}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathord}{mcy}{"58}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
@.\mathrm{Ker}\beta @>>>
\mathrm{Ker}\phi_S\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
0@>>>H^1(G_S,E[n])@=H^1(G_S,E[n])\\
@VVV @VV\beta V @VV\phi_S V \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^*@>      
{\psi}^{-1}\circ \lambda^*>>\bigoplus_{v\in S} {H^1(G_{K_v},E[n])}@>\lambda>>\bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n] \\
@V = VV @V h VV \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^*@>j>>\mathrm{Coker}\beta. \\ \end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}



Please show an example without babel in which the diagram is displayed correctly. This does not look like tikz-cd code at all

you don't need the babel library if you are only using english. I wouldn't bet against @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. that's like no tikzcd code I've ever seen. off-topic: mathtools loads amsmath, which loads amssymb; you should load hyperref last, probably. don't load color. tikz loads xcolor anyway. don't load things twice.

@cfr Ulrike fixed most of the "load hyperref last"-problems.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I thought it was still recommended to load it last, though? but perhaps even that has changed? you have better information than I do.

@cfr As far as I understand the current recommendation is: if you notice a problem, tell the latex team and maybe it can be fixed.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ah, OK. though later still seems safer .... but I wouldn't comment on it for that reason, so thanks.

You're using the arrow denotations of the obsolete CD environment which aren't understood by tikz-cd.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,arrows,arrows.meta,cd} % babelとtikzの互換性を確保

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=Straight Barb},
}

\newcommand*{\isoarrow}[1]{\arrow[#1,"\rotatebox{90}{\(\simeq\)}"]}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathord}{mcy}{"58}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em]
&[1em] \Ker\beta \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \Ker\phi_S \arrow[d] \\
0 \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
  & H^1(G_S,E[n]) \arrow[r,equals] \arrow[d,"\beta"]
  & H^1(G_S,E[n]) \arrow[d,"\phi_S"] \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^* \arrow[r,"{\psi}^{-1}\circ \lambda^*"] \arrow[d,"="]
  & \bigoplus_{v\in S} {H^1(G_{K_v},E[n])} \arrow[r,"\lambda"] \arrow[d,"h"]
  & \bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n] \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^* \arrow[r,"j"]
  & \Coker\beta
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

I reduced the column spacing, except between the first and second ones.
Note also that \mathrm{Ker}\beta has wrong spacing.


Your code isn't for tikz-cd - it does not matter if with or without babel.
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amscd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{CD}
@.\mathrm{Ker}\beta @>>>
\mathrm{Ker}\phi_S\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
0@>>>H^1(G_S,E[n])@=H^1(G_S,E[n])\\
@VVV @VV\beta V @VV\phi_S V \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^*@>      
{\psi}^{-1}\circ \lambda^*>>\bigoplus_{v\in S} {H^1(G_{K_v},E[n])}@>\lambda>>\bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n] \\
@V = VV @V h VV \\
\bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[n]^*@>j>>\mathrm{Coker}\beta. \\ 
\end{CD}
 \]

\end{document}



Thank you for your answer. I added amscd to the code in my question, but my diagram is broken...

@BrauerManinobstruction Don't use amscd. Instead write code for tikz-cd
